# API calls returns nothing in jenkins [redhat6.7]

Tags: unix, curl, jenkins, redhat

I am trying to get the curl output from a Unix machine for a jenkins job which should return the last build status, but the call once done returns nothing and fails with error:

```
error : curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

here is the curl command:

```
curl -u https://username:password@<hostname>/job/<jobname>/lastbuild/api/json
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Solved using 
curl --noproxy "*" <url>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your user/pass is correct. And then the command should be either of the following:

```
curl https://username:password@<hostname>/job/<jobname>/lastbuild/api/json
```

or

```
curl -u "username:password" https://<hostname>/job/<jobname>/lastbuild/api/json
```

Comment: user password is correct but still the error is same i have tried both the curl commands
giving error : "curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT"